# Calculating the number of perfect squares, perfect cubes,etc in a given range?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I know that we can use the formula `math.floor(b**(1.0/i))-math.ceil(a**(1.0/i))+1`
to calculate the number of squares in a given range, Does it hold when I want to find the number of perfect cubes,etc?

UPDATE: For all the people facing this issues, floor and ceil functions do not work well after square root, cube root, etc.

Comment: What values doesn't it work for?  Is this a problem with python or with your algorithm?

Comment: Algorithm I believe?

Comment: For example: in the range 32,64.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @MBo I'm rewriting in Java. Some problem with Python's floor and ceiling functions?

Comment: Not with particular language - with float numbers in general. 64**1/3 could have value like ~3.99999975, so floor gives 3. Or 4.000000016, so ceil gives 5 (I did not check real value). You must take numerical errors into account.

Comment: @MBo Got it. So the algorithm holds I believe then? If the value are calculated with proper precision?

Comment: @MBo is there an other approach to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float numbers calculations [are not exact](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

64**1/3 could have value like ~3.99999975, so `floor` gives 3. Or 4.000000016, so `ceil` gives 5 (I did not check real value). You must take numerical errors into account.

For this task you can calculate root (using ** or Math.Pow), and check the difference with floor-ed and ceil-ed values. If difference is very small, check  whether this root is exact one - in integers using multiplication.

Comment: Thanks this fixed a lot of issues, but I still get wrong answers for a few values. I've updated the code.

Comment: Have you compared high, low values with true values?